# Move specific array items to beginning of array without altering order of the rest

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [product1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [title] => 'p1'
        [extra] => Array(
            [date] => '1990-02-04 16:40:26'
        )
    )

    [product2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [title] => 'p2'
        [extra] => Array(
            [date] => '1980-01-04 16:40:26'
        )
    )
    [product3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [title] => 'p3'
        [extra] => Array(
            [date] => '2000-01-04 16:40:26'
        )
    )
    [product4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [title] => 'p4'
        [extra] => Array(
            [date] => '1995-01-04 16:40:26'
        )
    )
    [product5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [title] => 'p5'
        [extra] => Array(
            [date] => '1960-01-04 16:40:26'
        )
    )
    ...
```

I need to get 2 products with the latest date and move them to the start of the array.

I've looked into the multisort function, and I could sort the array like this, but then the entire array would be arranged by date, I want to maintain the order of the array but just bump up the latest 2 rows.

I need to pick out the 2 latest (order by date) from the array, then move these to the start of the array. So the order of the ids should be:

```
3,4,1,2,5
```

The latest 2 have been moved to the front of the array, the remainder are still ordered by id.

Comment: Can you post the expected output

Comment: Could you please provide some more information on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I've edited the question with what i'm trying to achieve

Comment: @Manashvibirla how will I know what elements to shift?

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: @panthro Its really unclear what you want to achieve can you post your expected output

Comment: The given array is impossible (duplicate keys), a real array sample would help.

Comment: @panthro is this var_dump?

Comment: Suggestion: use a two pass approach. Pick out a unique id of the items that you can use; worst case that's the array keys. Pass over the array once to filter out the two latest items; a `foreach` or `array_reduce` will do. Then do a [stable sort](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17365409/476), using the found ids as comparison criterion (if id == found id, always smaller, else equal).

Comment: I cannot give a var dump, I have simplified the data as the var dump would be huge.

Comment: Alternative: pass over the array to find the keys of the latest items (`foreach` or `array_reduce`), then `array_splice` and `array_merge` it back to together.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most optimal implementation, but the most straight forward:

```
$array = /* your data */;

$latest = $array;
uasort($latest, function (array $a, array $b) {
    return strtotime($a['extra']['date']) - strtotime($b['extra']['date']);
});
array_splice($latest, 2);

$latestOnTop = array_merge($latest, array_diff_key($array, $latest));
```

The `array_splice` operation requires that your array keys are actually `product1` or similar; won't work with numeric indices, as they'll be renumbered. Use another truncation mechanism if that's the case.

If your array is really big, a complete sort will be unnecessarily slow. In that case, you should rather loop over the array once, keeping track of the two latest items (and their keys) you could find, then `array_diff_key` and `array_merge` on that. That's a bit more difficult to implement (left as exercise for the reader), but much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Making array with only dates
$dates = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $item) 
    $dates[$key] = $item['extra']['date'];
// Sort it by date saving keys
uasort($dates, function($i1, $i2) { return  strtotime($i1) - strtotime($i2); });
// Take keys
$dates = array_keys($dates);
// Create array with two needed items
$newarray = array( $dates[0] => $arr[$dates[0]], $dates[1] => $arr[$dates[1]]);
// remove these items
unset($arr[$dates[0]]);  unset($arr[$dates[1]]); 
// put them in array start
$arr = array_merge($newarray, $arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// copy current array for new array
$temp = $input; 

// sort temp array by latest date
uasort($temp, function($a,$b) {
    return (strtotime($a['extra']['date']) < strtotime($b['extra']['date']));
});

// for 2 key value pairs to get on top
$sorted_keys = array_keys($temp);

// initialize your required array
$final = [];

// two keys to move on top
$final [ $sorted_keys[0] ] = $temp [ $sorted_keys[0] ];
$final [ $sorted_keys[1] ] = $temp [ $sorted_keys[1] ];

foreach ($input as $k => $v)
{
    // insert your other array values except two latest
    if(!array_key_exists($k, $final))
    {
        $final[$k]=$v;
    }
}

unset($temp); // free up resource
```

`$final` is your required array